# How to configure SharePoint to work for 2 different domains on the internet?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, moss, alternate-access-mappings

We have a SharePoint site which serves as our company site on the internet. Our company has 2 domains ".com" and ".co.uk". SharePoint works fine when you access the site using the ".com" domain. The problem is, when you try to access the site using the ".co.uk" domain, some pages (ones including custom lists, settings pages) do not work properly.

After doing some research, I found out that I needed to add the ".co.uk" domain under Sharepoint access mappings to make it work properly, but when I do that, I am redirected to the ".com" domain. By the way, the".com" domain already exists in the accesss mappings page.

So, what's the best way to configure our Sharepoint site to work for 2 different domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem today. Here's how:

1. First I learned how to extend a Sharepoint site using the video: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/Video/ff679931.
2. In SharePoint Central Administration, I extended the default site (SharePoint - 80) for the ".com" domain.

   - Used "Create a new IIS web site Name" option, used domain name as the name,
   - Used port 80, domain name as the host header and the default sharepoint path,
   - Didn't change Authentication and SSL options, allowed anonymous access
   - Used the ".com" domain in URL and used Internet as the zone.
3. After extending a new IIS site was created. In Internet Manager, I clicked "Edit Bindings" option for the new site. The ".com" domain was already set in bindings. I added the ".co.uk" domain into bindings as well.
4. In Central Administration > Alternate Access Mappings, I set the ".com" domain URL as the Default zone and the ".co.uk" domain as the Internet zone. This automatically added internal URLs for both domains.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the alternate address mapping create a IIS website for it.  This link might not 100% apply to what your using, but you should be able to make ends meet with it.

http://www.isaserver.org/img/upl/spskit/3quickstart/3quickstart.htm#_Toc58577520

Comment: Thanks for this Daniel, I'll check the link.